# .NET: Determining the URL of proxy

Tags: c#, web-services, proxy

I want to pass the proxy to my web service. I found the following code

```
MyWebService myService = new MyWebService(); 
System.Net.WebProxy proxyObject = 
    new System.Net.WebProxy("http://proxyserver:80/", true); 
myService.Proxy = proxyObject;  
myService.MyMethod();
```

How do I get "http://proxyserver:80/" dynamically?

Comment: I am not sure why do you want to get "http://proxyserver:80/" since this is a know proxy location to you. Can you please explain a little?

Comment: "http://proxyserver:80/" is an example of proxy location, I need to get this link dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
 proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
 webRequest.Proxy = proxy;
```

The [`GetSystemWebProxy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.webrequest.getsystemwebproxy.aspx) method reads the system proxy settings set up in Internet Explorer options. If that's not what you want, I'm afraid there is no way to automagically determine the address of some unknown proxy server.

Comment: what if the user use wireless connection

Comment: @AMH: as far as I know, it doesn't change much. Whatever you use to connect, system proxy settings exist. My code just uses them

Comment: final Question please , sometimes the user not select proxy, it's not be defined , is it be set automatically after connection

Comment: No, I don't think it will be. It's user's responsibility to specify the correct proxy settings in order to be able to reach remote resources